# Cors mode affects content type in fetch request

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch-api

I have the following code to post a multipart form:

```
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('FileContent', file.files[0]);
  data.append('Name', name.value);

  var config = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
      headers: {
      "Content-Type": undefined
    },
    mode: 'cors', //default
  }
  fetch('http://url.azurewebsites.net/test', config)
```

I explicity set `Content-Type` to undefined so that the browser automatically sets its properly with a random content part boundary:

> content-type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarychUCmr68Gnrt0ttG

That is not happening for me. The code above will generate a request header of:

> content-type:undefined

This totally breaks my server side processing, as the boundary needs to be passed so that my server code knows how to parse the multipart body. I am unclear why `undefined` is being passed as the request header value - the behaviour is consistent between Firefox and Chrome so I presume this isn't a browser bug.

Now, if I set `mode: no-cors`, then the correct header is applied:

> content-type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary...

But setting to this mode creates other problems I wish to avoid.

I have set up a service endpoint with a jsfiddle to illustrate. Open your dev tools and you can see how the request behaviour changes as you change the CORS mode.

http://jsfiddle.net/87u8zbyu/23/

I also note that the type of request changes based on the CORS mode. For the `cors` mode, the type is `text/plain`. For `no-cors` mode, the type is `fetch`.

I doubt it is germane to the issue, but if it helps here is my endpoint code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("test")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostTest()
    {
        try
        {
            //provider can not be created unless proper content-type is passed in as a header
            var provider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
            var formSize = provider.Contents.Count;
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(exc.Message),
                ReasonPhrase = "Bad Request"
            };
            throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan My god... It works. Many thanks for the input!

Comment: 4 years later, I just came across the exact same issue. Do you remember what was the solution?

Comment: @MisterEpic What worked? What was the solution?